# compile php application that contain javascript with Phalanger

Tags: php, compilation, phalanger

I want to compile a PHP application where I've used css files and javascript code.
I've choosed to work with Phalanger but I can't find any tutorial that mention how to compile such aplication. So is it possible , or Phalanger just compile php files ?

Answer (score 0):

Phalanger is server-side compiler of php code, and js is client-side script. This means Phalanger does not handle js, either in php files or in standalone js files. Js code in php files is simply outputted to the response as it would using regular php.

You can consider using additional tools for optimizing and minimizing js files.